# DNS Cache domains not resolving from external IP

Tags: domain-name-system, cache, dnsmasq

I am using dnsmasq on a CentOS box on an external network. My config file looks as follows:

```
port=53
bind-interfaces
user=root
group=dnsmasq
pid-file=/var/run/dnsmasq.pid
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-hosts
dns-forward-max=150 
cache-size=1000
neg-ttl=3600
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
no-poll
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
log-queries
```

When I set my computer's DNS IP to my VPS, no website resolves. I can see in the log file

Answer (score 0):

Centos by default has the [**iptables**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) firewall installed and running. The default configuration is quite restrictive. I suspect that you haven't made provision within your firewall configuration to allow access on port 53. To check

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -L | grep domain
```

if you get an output like this

```
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:domain
```

then port 53 is open and your problem lies elsewhere.

If you get a blank output then you will need to add rules to open port 53.

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
sudo /sbin/iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Then save the configuration

```
sudo /sbin/service iptables save
```